# Can PyCharm automatically export the Conda environment to environment.yml?

Tags: pycharm, export, conda, environment

Is there a way to export the active Conda environment by PyCharm itself into a yml file? Something similar to `Tools -> Sync Python Requirements...` menu item!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there is no such ability at the moment, it is only possible to create conda environment from yml file.